# Python: parsing and extracting op-codes from asm

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to parse an assembly file and extract only the opcodes, stripping-of the operands. Each line in the input file consists of exactly 3 opcodes. Should I extract the first word after the "[" in each line and accumulate in list ? Is there a better way of doing this?

**Here is my input file format**:

```
[slli a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8] [l32i a11,a3,128]
[add.n a3,a3,a8] [l32i a11,a3,128] [l32r a9,0x1fff8954]
[l32i a11,a3,128] [l32r a9,0x1fff8954] [l32i.n a10,a11,4]
[l32r a9,0x1fff8954] [l32i.n a10,a11,4] [l8ui a8,a11,0]
```

**My Expected output should be something like this**:

```
[ slli  : add.n  : l32i   ]
[ add.n : l32i   : l32r   ]
[ l32i  : l32r   : l32i.n ]
[ l32r  : l32i.n  : l8ui  ]
```

Comment: Your approach sounds reasonable to me...

Comment: what is the reason for the colons in the expected output?

Comment: @cchristelis : That's just for distinguishing opcodes. I can add-in a space or comma instead.

Comment: @user3769674 great and your input is a string?

Comment: @cchristelis  Yes, its a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finding op-codes:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\[(?=([a-z0-9.]+))','[slli a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8] [l32i a11,a3,128]')
['slli', 'add.n', 'l32i']
```

You should wrap that into a function.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy to do with regular expressions.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\[(\S+)')
output = []
with open('inputfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        output.append(pattern.findall(line))
```

Now you have a list of opcode lists.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(output)
[['slli', 'add.n', 'l32i'],
 ['add.n', 'l32i', 'l32r'],
 ['l32i', 'l32r', 'l32i.n'],
 ['l32r', 'l32i.n', 'l8ui']]
```

This list can then be processed to produce your required output, e.g.

```
>>> for line in output:
...     print '[ %s ]' % ' : '.join(line)
...
[ slli : add.n : l32i ]
[ add.n : l32i : l32r ]
[ l32i : l32r : l32i.n ]
[ l32r : l32i.n : l8ui ]
```